# Can I use single NSObject class for multiple ViewController class to get data from API

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject

I am try to use single NSObject class in which I am defined all variable those data access from server. I have multiple ViewController class those have different types of variable and string. I want to use single NSObject class to get data from server.
Is it possible?
For ViewControllerA string objects-

```
var id = Int()
    var contactowner = String()
    var status : String?
    var image:String?
    var title : String?
```

For ViewControllerB string objects-

```
var strImageRequesterName : String?
    var strRequesterName : String?
    var strRequesterPosition : String?
    var strRequesterAddress : String?
```

Comment: You need to understand how to use singletons: https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Answer (score 0):

of course you can , there are so much methord to do that , but i think this is a classic ‘Observer design Pattern’ [Observer Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)

Comment: it works perfect if i use same category API-  https://www.facebook.com/API1/                   https://www.facebook.com/API2/                                                                  but not if i used different category API-               https://www.google.co.in/API1/                                                                        in my project.

Comment: i think design pattern api is not a good idea for beginner. you should see some book first maybe,  for example ,<head first design pattern>, try again and again  , your will be better~

Comment: don't underestimate me just because of my stackOverflow reputation. I am working with live Project . so i don't think to read <head first design pattern>. by the way thank a lot . glad to talk with you.   :)

Comment: Actually  <michael> i am trying to reduce the memory consumption of any project, because when we create any project we need to create multiple NSObject class according to ViewController class , but i am trying to handle these NSObject classes into a single class.

Comment: and those API just for example. because i can't share original API's here due to company norms.

Comment: got it this time... I'm not good at English,sorry for my missunderstood.

Comment: Hey  @Michael' i got it . now i am sure. We can just using a single NSObject/Model  class for get data from different API.

Comment: how did you do that? please show me~   I did not meet this problem before, it is interesting~

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, Use [object Mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) with [alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for request fire and getting data in the form of objects and use callback function to get data from api, from service class.

Comment: In an answer, please make a code example for the user to replicate or view